# Regarding SQL Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is as follows :

My question is regarding SQL code for the following question.

Final query should return the vendor information along with the values from the table cb_vendorinformation.

You should combine the values of the two tables based on the GroupID column.

The final query should only print out the GroupID, CompanyName, and final count of all rows that are grouped into each company name under a column titled Count.

The output table should be then sorted by the Count column and then sorted by GroupID so that a higher number appears first.

This is the main table :

[image: maintable]

The output should look like this :

[image: finaloutput]

I could develop a code as follows but I am not getting the correct output :

```
SELECT m.GroupID, c.CompanyName, Count(*) as count
FROM maintable_KN01N m
  INNER JOIN cb_vendorinformation c  ON m.GroupID = c.GroupID
```

My output :

[image: my output]

Expected output :

[image: expected output]

Could someone please help me out here ?

I tried this code :

```
SELECT m.GroupID
     , c.CompanyName
     , Count(*) as count 
  FROM maintable_KN01N m 
  JOIN cb_vendorinformation c  
    ON m.GroupID = c.GroupID 
 GROUP 
    BY m.GroupID
     , c.CompanyName;
```

And was getting the output as follows :

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCVmo.png)

Comment: No need to `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Yeah so I am getting only one row as the output ? I think we would need to group by. But by what column ?

Comment: Try `GROUP BY m.GroupID, c.CompanyName` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, Jarlh it did work as I could get multiple rows. Thanks for that :) , but I am getting incorrect output now.

Comment: May be the count is different from expected ? I can attach the latest output above !

Comment: Output2 is still incorrect.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output as text which we can use rather than images which we cannot use.

Comment: I think the count is different

Comment: Hi, it's actually images from a webpage

Comment: I am suspicious about joining on 1 column and grouping by 2 but without useable data..

Comment: Hi could you please let me know how do I sort it with count ?

Comment: Like how do I group by count ? @jarlh

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: Put everything needed to ask your question in your post as text. Not as image/link. An added link to running online is OK. Before asking re your overall goal in another question if necessary, ask a question about your bad code. Not both. Find the first subexpression that doesn't return what you expect & say what you expect & why, justified by the manual/documentation. [mre] But it's probably a faq. Before considering posting, google many clear concise phrasings of you problem without your particular strings & line numbers, with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use `ORDER BY` as follows:

```
SELECT m.GroupID,c.CompanyName,Count(*) as count_ 
  FROM maintable_KN01N m 
 INNER JOIN cb_vendorinformation c ON m.GroupID=c.GroupID 
 GROUP BY m.GroupID,c.CompanyName 
 ORDER BY count_, m.GroupID desc;
```

Comment: no need to add count_ as an alias you can simply use alias as Count and one more thing you forgot to add c.CompanyName in the ORDER BY ... DESC section. Otherwise it will give wrong output.